# Can't write the right if statement regarding time

Tags: php, html

I have a database with rows of employee information. In the data I have training dates that expire. I need to compare the expiration date that is pulled to the current date. I'd like to bold and turn red the date if it is within 30 days of expiring. So anytime the page is loaded if it is within that 30 day time frame it will stand out.

This is what I have currently without the if statement I am looking for:

```
$lic_ex = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['lic_ex']));
echo "<td>" . $lic_ex . "</td>";
```

Comment: How is the date field stored in the DB?

Comment: With the standard DATE type in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert expiration date in DateTime object.
2. Create DateTime object which represents today date + 30 days.
   `$thirtyDaysLater = (new \DateTime('today'))->modify('+30 day');`
3. Compare both objects and if DateTime object from 2. is bigger, then the person is in 30 days expiration period and you can bold the text
   For example:

```
$expirationDate= DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y' , $input);
$compareDate = (new \DateTime('today'))->modify('+30 day');

if ($compareDate >= $expirationDate) {
    echo "<td><strong>" . $lic_ex . "<\strong></td>";
} else {
    echo "<td>" . $lic_ex . "</td>";
}
```

just adjust the createFromFormat parameters to your data

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thank you so much!